# Apache wicket - Add image using an http URL as src

Tags: html, image, wicket

I'm trying to add an img tag to a wicket page. I have not the image as file, I have its URL. I retrieve the URL using a REST service that is consumed in the page constructor.

I tried the following code, but it didn't work (I got a Failed to find markup file associated exception):

```
image = new Image("chart-img", title);
add(image);
image.getMarkupAttributes().put("src", url);
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks 
Laura

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this also

```
Image image = new Image("chart-img", "");
image.add(new AttributeModifier("src", url);
image.add(new AttributeModifier("title", title);
add(image);
```

Answer (score 2):

You just use a WebmarkupContainer for that:

```
image = new WebMarkupContainer("chart-img") {
  protected void onComponentTag(final ComponentTag tag)
  {
    super.onComponentTag(tag);

    tag.put("src", url);
    tag.put("title", title);
  }
};
add(image)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since some time there is also `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.image.ExternalImage` for exactly this use case.